# How to sort an array by the closest number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to sort an array by the closest item to a specific number

The following solution doesn't work in all cases, for no reason

```js
let array = [{"price":"6850000"},{"price":"6692301"},{"price":"6880000"},{"price":"6735100"},{"price":"6708900"},{"price":"7000000"}]

var price = 6692300
const closestArray = array.sort((a, b) => {
  if (Math.abs(b.price - price) > Math.abs(a.price - price)) {
      return b.price
  } else {
      return a.price
  }
})

console.log(closestArray)
```

IT works with this example :

```js
let array = [401,402,400,478,421,432]

var price = 400
const closestArray = array.sort((a, b) => {
    if (Math.abs(b - price) < Math.abs(a - price)) {
        return b
    } 
})

console.log(closestArray);
```

Comment: When you say closest, then you should using `Math.abs()` to compare the difference instead.

Comment: _"...doesn't work in all cases"_ - And those cases are?

Comment: @Terry I have just tried using Math.abs(), and it's giving me the same wrong sort

Comment: `return -1` instead of `return b.price` and `return 1` instead of `return a.price`

Comment: The [compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) has to return _"less than zero"_, _"zero"_ or _"greater than zero"_

Comment: @Aplet123 's answer is what you're looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases you are returning a positive number. That is to say, in both cases you are returning `>0`. Which means your code is really doing:

```
  if (Math.abs(b.price - price) > Math.abs(a.price - price)) {
      sort b before a
  } else {
      sort b before a
  }
```

Basically your `if` statement is not doing anything.

What you really want is:

```
  if (Math.abs(b.price - price) > Math.abs(a.price - price)) {
      return 1
  } else {
      return -1
  }
```

or

```
  if (Math.abs(b.price - price) > Math.abs(a.price - price)) {
      return -1
  } else {
      return 1
  }
```

depending on weather you want to sort ascending or descending.

Better yet you really should be doing:

```
return Math.abs(b.price - price) - Math.abs(a.price - price)
```

or

```
return Math.abs(a.price - price) - Math.abs(b.price - price)
```

Comment: _"Better yet you really should be doing"_ - Why? What's wrong with an `if...else...`

Comment: If .. else does not handle the zero case. Minus can return >0, <0 or 0 which will give you a more predictable, stable sort (does not switch ties unnecessarily). Even if you add and `else if`. The arithmetic code is smaller, more mathematically correct, easier to read and understand and uses fewer CPU instructions (one single instruction instead of subtract, compare, branch which is worse with else..if because it would do it twice) so is faster

Comment: The zero case yes. The rest is not true (math is the same) or in case of JS not relevant (CPU cycles, when there are multiple layers of software between the instruction and the actual cpu). But nevertheless you might want to add at least the zero case in your answer as explanation for the _,"better"_ way

Answer (score 1):

I believe this works.

```
let array = [{"price":"6850000"},{"price":"6692301"},{"price":"6880000"},{"price":"6735100"},{"price":"6708900"},{"price":"7000000"}]

var price = 6692300;
const closestArray = array.sort((a, b) => {
    const distOne = a.price - price;
    const distTwo = b.price - price;
    return Math.abs(distOne) - Math.abs(distTwo);
});

console.log(closestArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you were doing was that you were returning a price but that price was always greater than 0 which is supposed to return a number greater than 0 only if the second one, or b, should come first.

```js
let array = [{"price":"6850000"},{"price":"6692301"},{"price":"6880000"},{"price":"6735100"},{"price":"6708900"},{"price":"7000000"}];

var price = 6692300;
const closestArray = array.sort((a, b) => {
  if (Math.abs(b.price - price) < Math.abs(a.price - price)) {
      return 1;
  } else if (Math.abs(b.price - price) > Math.abs(a.price - price)) {
      return -1;
  }
  return 0; // because they are equal in value and should have equal ordering
})

console.log(closestArray);
```